# Radially symmetric system of PDEs in deal.II

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, deal.ii

I am trying to solve the radially symmetric polar form of the PDE with homogeneous Neumann BC in deal.II on a unit circle:
$$ u_t = \Delta u - \nabla \cdot (u \nabla h) $$
$$ h_t = \Delta h $$

1. I am not sure how to handle the origin & how the bilinear form change in this case.
2. Also, how to use the grid and triangulation in deal.II.

Could someone please explain or suggest similar literature?

Comment: Are you planning to use polar coordinates for this problem? Otherwise, there is not special treatment for the origin. Have you tried computing the weak form of your system?

Comment: The question of how the weak form of this problem should look like is fair for this site. The question of how to do this in deal.II is better asked on the deal.II mailing list.